# Receiver: null E/flutter ( 4835): Tried calling: []("Data")

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to fetch out the JSON value in flutter variable, but it shows

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'int' has no instance method '[]'.
E/flutter ( 4835): Receiver: 1
E/flutter ( 4835): Tried calling: []("Data")
```

what causes this, Where I am getting wrong
Future Function Code:

```
 Future<void> saveData(dynamic jsonOfUser) async {
    setState(() {
      isUploading = true;
    });
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: MyConstant.VAL_SECONDS), () {});
    return post(
      MyConstant.URL_USER_INSERT_LOGIN,
      body: jsonOfUser,
    ).then((onRecievedResponse) {
      var recievedValue = json.decode(onRecievedResponse.body);
      status = recievedValue["status"];
      userData = recievedValue[1]["Data"][5]["type"];

      print(userData);
      userInputValidation();

      print(recievedValue);

      setState(() {
        isUploading = false;
      });
      return null;
    });
  }
```

I want to fetch the value of type from data

```
{
"status": 1,
"data": [
{
"id": "304",
"name": "Name1",
"username": "User Name1",
"password": "Pass1",
"type": "1"
}
]
```

Here is the Class for Http call:

```
class MyConstant {
  static const String BASE_URL_ = 'http://95b5bc9c992c.ngrok.io/';

  static const String URL_API = BASE_URL_ + 'fyp/';
  static const String URL_Symptoms = 'http://531c3f6becb9.ngrok.io/?symptoms=';

  static const String URL_USER_INSERT = URL_API + 'user_signup.php';
  static const String URL_USER_INSERT_LOGIN = URL_API + 'user_login.php';
  static const String URL_USER_Symptoms = URL_API + 'user_symptoms.php';
  static const int VAL_SECONDS = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
`recievedValue["data"][0]["type"]`

Comment: It's not working, I have already tried it. Could you please edit the code the way you are telling.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `userData = recievedValue["Data"][0]["type"];`
It's better to use model classes to read Json as that makes code readable and also ease the process of reading JSON values.

```dart
 Future<void> saveData(dynamic jsonOfUser) async {
    setState(() {
      isUploading = true;
    });
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: MyConstant.VAL_SECONDS), () {});
    return post(
      MyConstant.URL_USER_INSERT_LOGIN,
      body: jsonOfUser,
    ).then((onRecievedResponse) {
      Map<String, dynamic> res = json.decode(onRecievedResponse.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      var recievedValue = UserData.fromJson(res)
      status = recievedValue.status;
      userData = recievedValue.data[0].type;

      print(userData);
      userInputValidation();

      print(recievedValue);

      setState(() {
        isUploading = false;
      });
      return null;
    });
  }
```

Model class

```dart
class UserData {
  int status;
  List<Data> data;

  UserData({this.status, this.data});

  UserData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = <Data>[];
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data.add(Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['status'] = status;
    if (data != null) {
      data['data'] = data.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  String id;
  String name;
  String username;
  String password;
  String type;

  Data({this.id, this.name, this.username, this.password, this.type});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    username = json['username'];
    password = json['password'];
    type = json['type'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['id'] = id;
    data['name'] = name;
    data['username'] = username;
    data['password'] = password;
    data['type'] = type;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: UserData class tojson function showing the error. it says The argument type 'MapEntry<?, ?> Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic> Function(String, dynamic)'.dartargument_type_not_assignable
The method 'toJson' isn't defined for the type 'String'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'toJson'.

Comment: If I directly want to fetch the type value of type. Do I still need to make the UserData class.

Comment: You can directly fetch the value as well. The model class should be fine as it's auto-generated, can you update your answer with what package are you using for calling your API? Is it Http or Dio ?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have updated my code please take a look.